# How to get input from user in Android Studio in numeric value and Convert it into variable int in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Hello everyone I am trying to make Calculator in Android Studio , As I am new Kotlin and Java therefore it is difficult for me.

Here is the source code of mine mainActivity xml file :

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName|number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.094"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.753"
    tools:hint="First Number"
    android:numeric="integer|decimal"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="none|textPersonName|number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.094"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText1"
    tools:hint="Second Number"
    android:numeric="integer|decimal"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="217dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:text="Answer"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/okactivity2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.095"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />
```

And here is my Android mainActivity.kt file

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

    okactivity2.setOnClickListener{
        val num1 = editText1.text
        val user1: Int = num1
        val num2 = editText2.text
        val user2: Int = num2
         val sum = user1 + user2
        editText3.setText("Answer is $sum")

    }

}
```

Here i am unable to convert string editText1 and editText2 into an int , so that i can set ediText3 As Answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EditText`'s `text` property is of type `Editable`. You'll need to transform it to `String` first, and then convert it to an `Int`:

```
val num1 = editText1.text.toString().toInt()
```

Answer (score 1):

Change input type in android xml file:

```
android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
```

And use this code :

```
val num = editText1.text.toString().toDouble()
```

Use `Double` to take input in Decimal or use `toInt()` to Convert in Integer.